Kendo React Dropdown with kendo react form Field
I am using the kendo react from and kendo reacts MultiSelect. In the edit case, Talrik form not set the MultiSelect values that are already selected.
The library versions are
"@progress/kendo-react-form": "^8.2.0", and "react": "^18.3.1",
import { MultiSelect } from "@progress/kendo-react-dropdowns";

 const selectedVal = [{
  "value": "9154a0f9-0c0f-427f-c6fe-08dccd9feaa1",
  "text": "Loan Broker",
 }]

 const data = [
  {
    "value": "a87fd0da-3f2a-4a43-c6fd-08dccd9feaa1",
    "text": "Real Estate Broker",
  },
  {
    "value": "9154a0f9-0c0f-427f-c6fe-08dccd9feaa1",
    "text": "Loan Broker",
  },
  {
    "value": "f231c4fa-3133-426b-c6ff-08dccd9feaa1",
    "text": "Direct Lender",
  }
 ];
<Form
    ignoreModified={true}
    onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    initialValues={updateInitialValues}
    render={(formRenderProps) => (
      <FormElement>
<CRow className="mb-3">
          <CCol xs={6}>
            <Label htmlFor="roles" className="mb-1">
              Contact Type(s)
            </Label>
            <Field
              name="roles"
              component={MultiSelect}
              data={data} 
              defaultValue={selectedVal} 
              textField="text" 
              dataItemKey="value" 
              className="custom-multiselect form-control-custom"
              placeholder="Select contact type..."
              onChange={handleChangeMultiSelect} 
            />
          </CCol>

        </CRow>
 </FormElement>
    )}
  />

On page reload the values are unselected. Or does it work only without Field component. And also the same type of issue faced with KendoReact ComboBox
